# GuideLine relative to another object

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

You need to make GuideLine relative to another object, and not relative to the screen. While I am using this:

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.875"
```

Comment: what is not working or what is expected?

Comment: this attribute spreads out objects relative to the entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layout_constraintGuide_percent` is always a percentage of the parent *ConstraintLayout's* height or width. You can continue to use a *GuideLine*, but you will have to manipulate the percentage programmatically either [directly](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet#setGuidelinePercent(int,%20float)) or through a facility like [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

You can set the placement of a widget at 87.5% of the width  (or height) of a widget with the use of another widget. Here is how you can do that:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewWeNeedPercentageOf"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space85_7"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/viewWeNeedPercentageOf"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.857"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/viewWeNeedPercentageOf"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/viewWeNeedPercentageOf" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewToBePositioned"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/viewWeNeedPercentageOf"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/space85_7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/viewWeNeedPercentageOf" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`viewWeNeedPercentageOf` is just the view we need to locate the `viewToBePositioned` within at 85.7% of its width.

`space85_7` is a [Space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space) widget that we will place at 85.7% of the width of `viewWeNeedPercentageOf`. We do this by setting its start and end constraints to the start and end of `viewWeNeedPercentageOf` and changing its horizontal bias to `0.875`. The visibility is set to `gone` so it has zero width and height.

We can now constrain the start side of `viewToBePositioned` to the space widget so it will now take the position that is 85.7% of the width  of `viewWeNeedPercentageOf`

[image]

Comment: thanks! I didn't understand before how to apply shift. I see you are using start instead of left.